# Slow internet with Ubuntu 20.04 and Realtek rtl8723be

Tags: wireless

I had issues with my internet connection after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.

The current situation is as follows:

1. If I connect my computer to the main wifi (where all my other devices are connected to), I rarely get a connection. It's spotty, slow and mostly nonexistent.
2. If I connect to a repeater, I get slightly better connection.
3. If create a hotspot on my smart phone and connect my computer to it, I get excellent connection.

All my other devices are connected to the main router without problems (smart phones, TV, other laptops). There is only one laptop that I cannot connect and it's the one that has Ubuntu LTS 20.04. Note that I was able to upgrade over the interned from the 18.04 version with no problems.

I read several posts about what I thing are similar problems, but nothing worked. Maybe the solution is to re-install Ubuntu?

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 24 Feb 2021 09:13 EST -0500

Booted last: 24 Feb 2021 00:00 EST -0500

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.4.0-65-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:25:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'exit'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf line 3: ignoring bad line starting with 'ls'

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Foxconn WLAN Realtek Sanji RTL8723BE bgn 1x1 + BT 4 LE PCIe+USB NGFF 2230 M.2 WW
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b50d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bc2:3300 Seagate RSS LLC Desktop         
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8723be             102400  0
btcoexist             155648  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                90112  4 rtl_pci,rtl8723be,btcoexist,rtl8723_common
mac80211              843776  3 rtl_pci,rtl8723be,rtlwifi
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
cfg80211              704512  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
wmi                    32768  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.0.15/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 42777sec preferred_lft 42777sec
    inet6 fe80::99be:f67c:eb4c:b04e/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"0017508204"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC '0017508204' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1133   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.15 metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[644 root '/etc/resolv.conf']
nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         609       1  0 08:22 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8723be
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.4.0-65-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:02:00.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlan0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     0017508204
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       f493740d-38bd-494f-8d61-562e1aef0549
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     72 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.15/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             24.154.1.68
IP4.DNS[2]:                             24.154.1.34
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name_servers = 24.154.1.68 24.154.1.34
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        expiry = 1614218793
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        host_name = nuno-HP-Stream-Notebook
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.0.15
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        next_server = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::99be:f67c:eb4c:b04e/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/6
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   f493740d-38bd-494f-8d61-562e1aef0549 | 0017508204

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBt
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bluez
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E8_36_17_05_F6_EB
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
BLUETOOTH.CAPABILITIES:                 NAP
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/10
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d85336bd-a5de-4c5f-8386-7ac0611fd5eb | iPhone Network

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifiP2P
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID        BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE 
0017508204  <MAC '0017508204' [AC1]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  195 Mbit/s  64      â–‚â–„â–†_  WPA1 WPA2  yes     *      
--          <MAC '' [AC2]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  65 Mbit/s   40      â–‚â–„__  --         no             

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Panera]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Panera | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Panera | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/iPhone.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=iPhone | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=iPhone
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TP-LINK_Extender_568017]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TP-LINK_Extender_568017 | type=wifi | permissions=user:nuno:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TP-LINK_Extender_568017
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WLAN_2E8C]] (600 root)
[connection] id=WLAN_2E8C | type=wifi | permissions=user:nuno:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=WLAN_2E8C
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MOVISTAR_3D28]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MOVISTAR_3D28 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MOVISTAR_3D28
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Thomson048FE5]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Thomson048FE5 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Thomson048FE5
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/0017508204.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=0017508204 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=0017508204
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CATZNET2G]] (600 root)
[connection] id=CATZNET2G | type=wifi | permissions=user:nuno:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=CATZNET2G
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SRU-Guest]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SRU-Guest | type=wifi | permissions=user:nuno:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SRU-Guest
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ANNE]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ANNE | type=wifi | permissions=user:nuno:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ANNE
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

global
country US: DFS-FCC
    (2400 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5730 - 5850 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 71000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC '0017508204' [AC1]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"0017508204"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000026fc3935180
                    Extra: Last beacon: 128ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC '' [AC2]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000026fc391c142
                    Extra: Last beacon: 256ms ago

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8723be
vermagic:       5.4.0-65-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
parm:           aspm:Set to 1 to enable ASPM (default 1)
parm:           debug_level:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           debug_mask:Set debug mask (default 0) (ullong)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
parm:           ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
depends:        rtlwifi
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8723_common
vermagic:       5.4.0-65-generic SMP mod_unload 

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl_pci
vermagic:       5.4.0-65-generic SMP mod_unload 

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtlwifi
vermagic:       5.4.0-65-generic SMP mod_unload 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-65-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.4.0-65-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-65-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.4.0-65-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723be]
ant_sel: 0
aspm: 1
debug_level: 0
debug_mask: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf]
exit
ls

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/sleep.d/config] (644 root)
SUSPEND_MODULES= "RTL8723"

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0xb723 (rtl8723be)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   17.711737] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC '0017508204' [AC1]>
[   17.729467] wlan0: send auth to <MAC '0017508204' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   17.732002] wlan0: authenticated
[   17.738312] wlan0: associate with <MAC '0017508204' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   17.765638] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC '0017508204' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[   17.765918] wlan0: associated
[   18.022633] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  276.690542] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC '0017508204' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  315.151677] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address>
[  315.164251] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[  315.224214] wlan0: authenticated
[  315.227974] wlan0: associate with <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[  315.234425] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  315.234758] wlan0: associated
[  315.458559] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC address>
[  325.238952] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  326.293183] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address>
[  326.316842] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[  326.321809] wlan0: authenticated
[  326.331487] wlan0: associate with <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[  326.369624] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  326.369911] wlan0: associated
[  326.396211] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  326.620152] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC address>
[ 2653.982347] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 2654.523827] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC '0017508204' [AC1]>
[ 2655.032388] wlan0: send auth to <MAC '0017508204' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2655.034529] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2655.036442] wlan0: associate with <MAC '0017508204' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2655.042752] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC '0017508204' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 2655.043005] wlan0: associated
[ 2655.091078] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 2):

In your paste, we see:

> libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse:
> /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with
> 'exit'

There is nothing helpful in the file; let's remove it:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Next, please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and *certainly not* TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Thank you again for your support.

I was able to remove the configuration file as you suggested. Can the problem be the driver for this Realtek equipment?

Router security, it is set to WPA & WPA2 Personal. It does not have a WPA-AES option. Other options are WEP, LEAP, Dynamic WEP and WPA3.

My regulatory domain is set to the US (correct), so I made no changes.

Currently I’ve been playing between connecting via my router, or a personal hotspot created by my phone. The phone seems to be working better. When I’m connected via the router, I end up loosing the connection after some time.

Comment: What is the make and model of the router. I'd like to look up its manual on line. TKIP is inserure and must not be used. I am surrised that *any* router doesn't allow you to deselect it.

Comment: If by router you mean the modem, it's a Arris, model DG2470A [https://arris.secure.force.com/consumers/articles/User_Guide/DG2470A-NA-User-Guide/?l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle].

Comment: UPDATE: This morning during the process of updating the software, I got the following message: [https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZkDMxdmDSz]. Does it help?

Comment: It means that dkms cannot successfully compile a driver for an rtl8188ee device. According to your previous paste, that's not at all what you have. I suggest that we remove it and all other unneeded dkms  drivers. Please let me see a paste of: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: Interesting, I should have rtl8723be. Here's the result of the dkms status: [https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/68brqs4kMG]

Comment: OK. The problem is definitely with the modem. If I connect to my normal wifi modem (the one every other equipment in the house is connected), I have all kinds of problems: no internet, spotty signal, etc. But if I connect to my phone's hotspot I have no problems whatsoever. I've been reading about the problems with the rtl8723be driver, but don't think that is the problem.

Comment: I give up! Re-installed ubuntu from usb drive and same thing: Connect to my main router and have spotty interned; connect to my iphone hot spot and works great!!! If anyone has ideas, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"
```

and reboot.

If that doesn't help, try `ant_sel=1`.

This will set the driver to use the correct antenna.

Answer (score -2):

Gave up and installed a USB wifi device. Read that the main problem with this laptop is the low range of the wifi internal antenna. This resolved the problem.

Comment: It is not low range. You were using a wrong antenna. It is fixable

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong antenna"? I have read several threads and many pointed out that the driver for this antenna was never upgraded. It is also true that I had smooth internet connection prior to upgrading Ubuntu. If this is fixable, I'm really interested in knowing how.

Comment: I mean that linux can't detect which antenna is physically connected if there is one antenna in the laptop. It can be easily fixed by setting a parameter.

Comment: I guess I don't know enough about this to agree or disagree with you. What I can tell you is that I tried everything I found, for months, and nothing worked. I installed this simple USB type antenna and puff... problem solved. If this can be fixed, at least I'll have an additional USB connection available : )

Comment: I wrote an answer about how to fix it.

Comment: My bad. Just saw it. I tried the command you mention above and could not get an internet connection. Just a warning that the "Connection to the Network Failed".